# Dynamic Page - accessing elements in events

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to create a dynamic page in pageload() event and how to call the values like textbox or radio button on an button click event or in any other events?

Kindly give a small example. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're going to need to show some research effort.. and possibly rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create create any ASP.NET control dynamically and add them to the Page.

TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();

If you have to access these values in the post-back. Then it is better to create them in Page_Init() than Page_Load(). If you are creating a dynamic element then you have to create them on every post-back.

There are some good articles on these topic. Google them